# How do I solve the non-homogeneous wave equation with homogeneous boundary and initial conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

I want to solve $$v_{tt}(x,t) - v_{xx}(x,t) = -\left(\frac{3}{4} \cos(t) + \frac{1}{4} \cos(3t)\right) \sin(x)$$ with boundary conditions
$$v(0,t) = v(\pi,t) = 0$$ and initial conditions $$v(x,0) = v_t(x,0) = 0.$$

I know that the solution must be of the form $v = v_h + v_p$, where $v_h$ is the solution of the homogeneous equation and $v_p$ is a particular solution.

Given the homogeneous equation and the BC and IC, it follows that $v_h = 0$. We therefore need to find a particular solution.

Is it justified to make the ansatz $v_p = A(t)B(x)$? If I expand B(x) into a Fourier series, is it justified to say that the only term surviving is the $c\sin(x)$ term, given the RHS? What can I say about A(t)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split up the solution to $v = w_1 + w_2 + u$ such that $u$ is homogeneous and $w_1$, $w_2$ are 2 particular solutions:

\begin{align}
w_{1tt}-w_{1xx} &= -\frac34\cos t\sin x \\
w_{2tt}-w_{2xx} &= -\frac14\cos 3t\sin x
\end{align}

The second particular solution is easy enough, it has the same form as the RHS function: $$w_2(x,t) = A\cos 3t\sin x $$

For the first particular solution, this guess will not work since $\cos t\sin x$ is a homogeneous solution. Think back to when you were solving ODEs, if we came across a similar situation, i.e

$$ y'' + y = \cos x $$

where the RHS is a homogeneous solution, we would add a factor of $x$ (the independent variable) to our particular guess, so it's $y_p(x) = Ax\cos x + Bx\sin x$. We can sort of do the same here, by adding either a factor of $t$ or $x$ into our particular solution, so $w_1$ can have one of these forms:

- $w_1(x,t) = \cos t(Ax\cos x + Bx\sin x)$
- $w_1(x,t) = (At\cos t + Bt\sin t)\sin x$

Ideally, we would like for this solution to also satisfy the boundary conditions, i.e. $w_1(0,t) = w_1(\pi,t)=0$ so as to not cause more problems down the line. Hence, the second particular form is superior. Plug that into the PDE to find the constants $A$, $B$.

Once you've found both particular solutions, it remains to solve

\begin{cases}
u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0 \\
u(0,t) = u(\pi,t) = 0 \\
u(x,0) = -w_1(x,0) - w_2(x,0) \\
u_t(x,0) = -w_{1t}(x,0) - w_{2t}(x,0) 
\end{cases}

which you can use separation of variables.

Comment: I will try this, thanks. Why do I have to add the particular solutions to the initial conditions of the homogeneous equation?

Comment: @jo_elk In order to preserve the initial conditions of the original function

Comment: Is this always the case when solving the homogeneous part of an inhomogeneous equation?

Comment: am I correct in assuming that this separation only works for homogeneous initial and boundary conditions?

Comment: Can you add a source where I can read about increasing the order of the polynomial in the ansatz when RHS is a homogeneous solution? I realize my knowledge about DEs is a bit rusty...

Comment: Initial conditions, no. Boundary conditions, yes. Moreover, you can only guess a particular solution if the inhomogeneous function has a "predictable form" such as trig functions, exponentials or polynomials (much like in ODEs). For general cases, you may refer to [these notes](http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_10.pdf)

Comment: For your last question, refer to the [method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients)